# What if the kinetic energy of a particle was some other function $f(v)$?

Tags: energy, symmetry, classical-mechanics

This is a "what if this was how the universe worked" kind of question.  I don't know if those belong in Physics StackExchange, and I apologize if they don't.

Suppose we have two reference frames connected by some linear transformation $x'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu$.  In a modern language, we thought the correct $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ was the Galilean transformation, and we concluded that kinetic energy was $\frac{1}{2} m v^2$.

Later, some smart people (Einstein and others) realized that $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ should be the Lorentz transformation.  Then, if one assumes momentum conservation and that kinetic energy is a line integral of $\frac{dp}{dt}$, one can reach the conclusion that kinetic energy is $(\gamma -1)mc^2$, which like $\frac{1}{2} m v^2$ is a function of $v^2$.

Now, lets work backwards.  Suppose we lived in an alternate universe, and suppose we knew that the kinetic energy of a particle of mass $m$ is

$$ \text{KE} =  m f(v)$$

where $f(v)$ is a smooth function of $v=|\vec{v}|$.  In the case of non-relativistic classical mechanics, $f(v)=\frac{1}{2}v^2$.

In our alternate universe (with its own symmetries, not necessarily Galilean or Lorentz), with an arbitrary $f(v)$, can we reconstruct the transformation $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ that connect different frames of reference in our alternate universe?  For every $f(v)$, does an associated $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ exist?  If so, is it unique?

Comment: I think what you're essentially asking is if Noether's Theorem is reversible (i.e. if a symmetry implies a conservation law can we instead start with a conservation law and find the necessary symmetry).  As far as I know, no one has proved that that Noether's Theorem works in the reverse.  Though, I'm not sure if anyone has proved that it cannot either.

Comment: It seems to me that implementation of the program outlined in the question would lead us to Finsler geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Lorentz symmetry clearly implies that
$$ E = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$
is the only correct form for energy as a function of the velocity $v$. The only other allowed type of formula is the $c\to\infty$ limit of the abovementioned expression which is
$$ E  = mc^2 + \frac{mv^2}{2}$$
and which contains the latent energy $mc^2$, too. It is the non-relativistic form of the energy. In the non-relativistic limit, the energy is determined up to a shift – only the energy differences are determined – so the velocity-independent term $mc^2$ doesn't spoil anything and may be forgotten in the non-relativistic limit, too. The next term, $mv^2$, is the leading velocity-dependent term in the Taylor expansion.

It's not hard to see that the first formula for energy follows from relativity i.e. that all other formulae are just wrong. The difference
$$ E^2 - p^2 c^2 = m^2 c^4$$
must be an invariant in the same sense in which $(ct)^2-x^2-y^2-z^2$ is an invariant under the Lorentz transformations. Using $pc^2/E=v$ as the expression from the velocity as a ratio of the momentum and the energy, this difference equation is equivalent to the first equation for the energy.

Comment: Hi Lubos!  Thanks for the reply, but that wasn't my question.  Lorentz symmetry implies a certain form for $E$.  However, if we lived in another universe (without Lorentz symmetry) where the energy was a different form $f(v)$, could we deduce the transformations (which will not be Lorentz) that connect two different frames of reference?

Comment: Dear Chickengod, there are no other physically consistent transformations that could related different reference frames. That's really the point. Lorentz and Galileo transformations - and the latter are a limit (contraction) of the former - are the only two options. That's why Einstein could have derived all these things from relativity. There is nothing adjustable about relativity. All these things are really derivable - unique.

Comment: So, you are saying that the Lorentz transformations are the only possible ways to connect different frames of reference?  What is the proof of this statement?  And what does that imply for those researchers who are looking for violations of Lorentz symmetry?

Comment: Yes, I am saying it. See e.g. the derivations in Einstein's 1905 papers on relativity. The inevitability of Lorentz transformations is what whole special relativity is all about. There are just not too many groups in mathematics, especially not groups that could look similar. What it implies for Lorentz violation researchers is that they are looking for a proof that different frames just can't obey the same laws. This - i.e. Lorentz violation - is heavily disfavored, nearly impossible, because all the usual theoretical and experimental evidence in favor of relativity.

Comment: Interesting.  I never read Einstein's papers, but I heard that it says that Lorentz symmetry must be true if Maxwell's Equations are true.  However, what you are saying is much stronger: we can deduce Lorentz symmetry without knowing Maxwell's Equations... all we need to know is that the laws of physics are the same in every reference frame.  That's something to really think about.  Thanks.

Comment: Dear ChickenGod, what you say about relativity and Maxwell's equations is very confusing. Einstein have figured out that the Lorentz symmetry is the right transformation to map inertial frames to each other - replacing the Galilean transformations - from Maxwell's equations. But the Lorentz symmetry may still be broken in principle even if the electromagnetic part of the world obeys Maxwell's equations. Well, it's not broken, but one can't really prove it in this way.

Comment: What Einstein assumed to derive the rest of relativity isn't Maxwell's equations. Instead, relativity builds on two assumptions, the so-called postulates: the constancy of the speed of light (regardless of velocities of observer, source), and the relativity principle that says that the laws should take the same form for observers in relative uniform motion. From these postulates, the Lorentz group and everything related including the right discpersion relations follows.

Comment: Yes, special relativity does follow from relativity principle and the constancy of the speed of light (which must be true for Maxwell's Equations be of the same form in every inertial frame).  However, in a hypothetical fictional universe without massless particles, we can drop the assumption that the speed of light is a constant.  This is what my original question was addressing.  Nevertheless, you are right that Lorentz invariance follows from very few rules, and so is very unlikely to be untrue.

Comment: You don't need massless particles to "see" the speed of light. The speed of light is still the speed that objects approach when their energy vastly exceeds the latent energy (rest mass times $c^2$). What matters for relativity is that there is a speed, actual or limiting, that has the same value for each observer. There may be "fictional universes" that don't respect relativity, of course, but it is not true that fictional universes without massless particles must violate relativity.